# Finding order of coset in quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Question: Let $N$ be the subgroup $\langle 4\rangle$ of $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$. Find the order of $13+N$ in the group $\mathbb{Z}_{20}/N$.

Work done: I've been trying to follow the process from this question: [Find order of element in a quotient group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89366/find-order-of-element-in-a-quotient-group)

NOTE: I'm going to suppress equivalent class notation (I'll write $[x]$ as  $x$).

I've written out the elements of the quotient group:
$\mathbb{Z}_{20}/N=\langle 4\rangle, 1 + \langle 4\rangle, 2+ \langle 4\rangle, 3 + \langle 4\rangle.$ I don't believe that any of these are equivalent to $13+N$. To my understanding, I want to find a positive integer $k$ so that $kN=\langle 4\rangle.$ The only one that I can see is 20. I don't think that is correct, though. I'm not sure that I understand what I'm supposed to be doing.

Comment: Notice that $12 \in \langle 4 \rangle$.  So, $13 \in 1 + \langle 4 \rangle$.

Comment: Of course. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$:

$$13-1=4\cdot3$$

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks. I wasn't thinking of the problem in the right manner.